# What postgres privileges are required for Apache Airflow database backend?

Tags: postgresql, airflow

Nothing is mentioned about this in the documentation about "initializing the backend" ([link](https://airflow.apache.org/howto/initialize-database.html)).

If I create an `airflow_user` role and an `airflow` schema. Is it sufficient if I grant `airflow_user` `USAGE` on `airflow` schema and then `SELECT UPDATE INSERT DELETE` on all tables? Does that user need `GRANT ALL` on all tables in the `airflow` schema?

Is it better to make `airflow_user` the owner of `airflow` schema which I understand will allow it all privileges inside that schema because it is the owner?

References:
Postgres `GRANT` ([link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-grant.html))
Postgres privileges ([link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-priv.html))
Unanswered SO question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51732323/airflow-metadata-db-permissions))

Answer (score 0):

It's not sufficient to create a schema.
The schema is not a configurable option in the DSN value configured for `AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN`.

libpq which psycopg2 driver depends upon [doesn't allow to configure `search_path`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_13_1/src/interfaces/libpq/fe-connect.c#L193) as an extra parameter in the DSN.

The best practice is to create a database for Airflow.

For example,

Copy to `create-airflow-db.sql`

```sql
create database airflow;
create user airflow;
alter user airflow with password 'airflow';
grant all on database airflow to airflow;
```

Start database server in container. Keep this running in a separate terminal.

```sh
docker run -it --rm \
--publish '5432:5432' \
-v $PWD/create-airflow-db.sql:/create-airflow-db.sql \
--name postgres \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres:alpine
```

Run query in the SQL file in a different terminal.

```sh
docker exec -ti postgres psql -w -U postgres -d postgres -f create-airflow-db.sql
```

Finally, run Airflow service in a new terminal.

```sh
docker run --rm \
-it \
-e 'AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql://airflow:airflow@172.17.0.1:5432/airflow' \
--publish '8080:8080' puckel/docker-airflow
```

You can connect to the database server and list the tables.

```
➜  airflow docker exec -ti postgres psql -w -U airflow -d airflow
psql (13.1)
Type "help" for help.

airflow=> \dt
                List of relations
 Schema |         Name          | Type  |  Owner
--------+-----------------------+-------+---------
 public | alembic_version       | table | airflow
 public | chart                 | table | airflow
 public | connection            | table | airflow
 public | dag                   | table | airflow
 public | dag_pickle            | table | airflow
 public | dag_run               | table | airflow
 public | dag_tag               | table | airflow
 public | import_error          | table | airflow
 public | job                   | table | airflow
 public | known_event           | table | airflow
 public | known_event_type      | table | airflow
 public | kube_resource_version | table | airflow
 public | kube_worker_uuid      | table | airflow
 public | log                   | table | airflow
 public | serialized_dag        | table | airflow
 public | sla_miss              | table | airflow
 public | slot_pool             | table | airflow
 public | task_fail             | table | airflow
 public | task_instance         | table | airflow
 public | task_reschedule       | table | airflow
 public | users                 | table | airflow
 public | variable              | table | airflow
 public | xcom                  | table | airflow
(23 rows)
```

Here you see that the tables backing Airflow models are created in the public schema or search path.